# Vertical Lines at steps of HeavsideTheta

Tags: plotting, piecewise

I want to plot the following:

```
Plot[{Sqrt[x], Sum[HeavisideTheta[x - n^2], {n, 1, Floor[x]}]}, {x, 0,50}]
```

which looks like

[image: sum of heaviside step functions]

Is there a simple way to get this same plot with vertical lines at the jumps between steps?

Comment: I'm not sure what happened but I was messing around and suddenly the steps appeared, I'm not sure why, the code is exactly the same, but now it is throwing this error:

`Plot::exclul: {Sin[\[Pi] Re[x]]-0,Sin[\[Pi] Im[x]]-0,Im[-n^2+x]-0,(-n^2+x)-0} must be a list of equalities or real-valued functions.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the option [`Exclusions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exclusions.html):

```
Plot[{Sqrt[x], Sum[HeavisideTheta[x - n^2], {n, 1, Floor[x]}]}, {x, 0, 50},
 Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

The only easy method I'm aware of is to make it a parametric plot instead.

```
wrapper[f_] := {#1, f[#1]} &;
ParametricPlot[
    {wrapper[Sqrt][x], 
    wrapper[Sum[HeavisideTheta[# - n^2], {n, 1, Floor[#]}] &][x]}
    , {x, 0, 50}
]
```

Produces the output:

[image]

I also receive this error you mention in your comment. I don't understand why; maybe `ParametricPlot` thinks the functions may not have real values. If you're confident there's no problem with your input, you can wrap `ParametricPlot` in `Quiet[ ... , ParametricPlot:exclul` to prevent this message from appearing.